# Disable the Windows 10 Password login option when FIDO in use

Tags: windows-10, entra-id, windows-authentication, microsoft-intune

Hello Collective intelligence,

I have a question that is bugging me,

I have a Yubikey 5C setup in Azure AD with passwordless auth and registered to my account, I can log into the PC using the FIDO key and PIN and have managed to get Windows 10 to lock when the key is removed.

What I am trying to do is remove the sign-in options specifically for the password and only allow FIDO logins.

I have read through the guide on this page: https://www.cloudservus.com/fido2-security-key-for-windows-10-part-1/ However, it only mentions part 2 to remove the password, and no link or other mention of part 2 that I can find.

My google foo is only showing "How to setup FIDO" which clearly I have already done (thanks google for not understanding the part of remove password option)

any help is appreciated =)

Answer (score 1):

You are right - part 2 of the guide has details on disabling password provider.
Here is the link: https://www.cloudservus.com/enforcing-passwordless-logins-with-aadj-windows-10-and-endpoint-manager-intune-part-2/

Comment: you are my hero, thank you very much